# Рекурсия и итерация

Tags: алгоритм

Всякую ли рекурсию можно превратить в итерацию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любой алгоритм, реализованный в рекурсивной форме, может быть переписан в итерационном виде  и наоборот. Останется вопрос, надо ли это, и насколько это будет это эффективно.

Для обоснования  можно привести такие доводы.

Для начала можно вспомнить определение рекурсии и итерации. Рекурсия - это такой способ организации обработки данных, при котором программа вызывает сама себя непосредственно, либо с помощью других программ. Итерация - это способ организации обработки данных, при котором определенные действия повторяются многократно, не приводя при этом к рекурсивным вызовам программ.

После чего можно сделать вывод, что они взаимно заменимы, но не всегда с одинаковыми затратами по ресурсам и скорости. Для обоснования можно привести такой пример: имеется функция, в которой для организации некого алгоритма имеется цикл, выполняющий последовательность действий в зависимости от текущего значения счетчика (может от него и не зависеть). Раз имеется цикл, значит, в теле повторяется последовательность действий - итерации цикла. Можно вынести операции в отдельную подпрограмму и передавать ей значение счетчика, если таковое есть. По завершению выполнения подпрограммы мы проверяем условия выполнения цикла, и если оно верно,  переходим к новому вызову подпрограммы, если ложно - завершаем  выполнение. Т.к. все содержание цикла мы поместили в подпрограмму, значит, условие  на выполнение цикла помещено также  в подпрограмму, и получить его можно через возвращающее значение функции, параметры передающееся по ссылке или указателю в подпрограмму, а также глобальные переменные. Далее легко показать, что вызов данной подпрограммы из цикла легко переделать на вызов, или не вызов (возврата значения или просто завершения работы) подпрограммы из нее самой, руководствуясь какими-либо условиями (теми, что раньше были в условии цикла). Теперь, если посмотреть на нашу абстрактную программу, она примерно выглядит как передача значений подпрограмме и их использование, которые изменит подпрограмма по завершению, т.е. мы заменили итеративный цикл на рекурсивный вызов подпрограммы для решения данного алгоритма.

Задача по приведению рекурсии  к итеративному подходу симметрична.

Подводя итог, можно выразить такие мысли: для каждого подхода существует свой класс задач, который определяется по конкретным требованиям к конкретной задаче.

Answer (score 1):

Любую. Можно в итерациями симулировать рекурсивную функцию, явно храня стек.

Comment: Дык это тоже самое что вызывать рекурсивную функцию, с той лишь разницей, что стек явный и им можно управлять. Алгоритм остаётся рекурсивным.

Comment: Нет, ни одного рекурсивного вызова в нем не останется

Comment: Да полно. Рассмотрим язык, в котором есть возможность объявлять рекурсивные функции, транслирующийся прямо в Си и затем компилирующийся. Таких языков много. Определение рекурсивной функции на этом языке после перевода на Си не будет рекурсивным, но сама функция будет рекурсивной.

Comment: Главное что код будет выполняться древовидно, а не в цикле.

Comment: Владимир, вы можете четко сформулировать что вы считаете рекурсивной функцией, а что - нерекурсивной? Без четких определений мне кажется спорить не имеет смысла)
Я например считаю, что функция называется рекурсивной в том случае если ее выполнение может привести к еще одному вызову ее самой (прямо или через другие функции). Соответственно, функция нерекурсивна в противном случае.

Comment: Рекурсивная функция -- такая, что её значение может быть вычислено только с помощью дочерних вызовов этой функции.

Comment: Тогда каким образом переделанная функция с явным стеком попадает под это определение, если она никогда не делает дочерних вызовов самой себя?

Comment: Она не попадает, правда. Окей, я сфейлил. Просто явный стек -- это тоже самое во что преобразуется функция при компиляции. Очень похоже. Просто записано иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Компиляторы gcc и msvc умеют разворачивать простую хвостовую рекурсию. Обычно когда пишу код, я пытаюсь сделать намного яснее, а выразительнее получается применяя рекурсию, если же надо оптимизировать этот участок, то можно и переписать на итерацию :-)

Comment: А что такое "простая" хвостовая рекурсия?

Comment: Хвосовая рекурсия это когда функция вызывает саму себя в самом конце. Если же после вызова самой себя требуется ещё что-то сделать, то это уже не хвостовая рекурсия.

Comment: Вопрос был про "простая"

Comment: И ответ тоже. https://gist.github.com/825720

Comment: Вы пример на brainfuck'e привели бы лучше :-D

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Пример: [Функция Аккермана](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%90%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) Превратить в итерацию можно только примитивно рекурсивную.

Comment: Использование явнообъявленного стека не спасает -- функция останется рекурсивной.

Comment: Вы путаете понятия. Есть рекурсивная функция. Она рекурсивная по определению. А есть рекурсия как приём программирования. Вы путаете понятия. Есть рекурсивная функция. Она рекурсивная по определению. А есть рекурсия как приём программирования. Любую рекурсивную функцию можно реализовать не применяя рекурсию как приём и наоборот: можно не-функцию (инмеративную реализацию некоего поведения) реализовать с помощью рекурсии.

Comment: Любую рекурсивную функцию можно реализовать не применяя рекурсию как приём?

Comment: Код можно записать так, что там не будет рекурсивных вызовов, но ведь он будет выполняться рекурсивно.

Comment: Это как?

Comment: Не будет он выполняться рекурсивно. Он будет выполняться в цикле + манипуляции со стеком. Не считаете же вы, что все операции в цикле со стеком являются рекурсией?

Comment: Вычисления будут выглядеть как дерево.

Comment: Чёрт, признаю, я ошибался.